# How to listen to incoming emails of multiple email accounts?

Tags: email, architecture, monitoring

I'd like to execute a function whenever a new email is received. It should work for any email service like gmail/outlook/yahoo etc. I found an [article](https://dev.to/akinmyde/reading-email-data-with-node-js-bjf) that can do this, but the issue here is that I need the users emails and passwords. I really don't want to store users credentials in my database, so I'm wondering if there's a better alternative.

One option that occurred to me is to use the individual email services APIs to listen for incoming emails after getting the permission to do so via OAuth. But it seems like it's going to be quite a bit of work to implement the same.

Better alternatives to solve the issue would be appreciated. Any ideas? I'm open to any languages to implement the same (except Java). Not asking for code, just trying to wrap my head around the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using OAuth is the way to go because it allows customers to send applications to their own email addresses without directly sharing their certificates. This is the safest and recommended method, although it may take some effort to implement.

You can simplify your implementation by following these steps:

Choose an authentication library: You can use libraries to implement OAuth for different languages ​​and platforms. For example, you can use the Python libraries google-auth and google-auth-oauthlib for Gmail and msal for Outlook.
Find out about your application: In order to get the required API credentials such as  client ID and secret key, you need to register your application with your messaging service provider.This must be done for each service (Google, Microsoft, Yahoo, etc.).
Get access token: Use your favorite library to rebuild an OAuth flow that generates an access token. This token can be used to access a customer's mailbox without their secret key. Instead of storing the user's credentials, you can securely store this token in your database.
Leverage email sinks: Create sinks for inbound email using the appropriate email service API. You can  use  the "Look" functionality of the Gmail API. Webhooks can be used with the REST API for Outlook notifications. You can use IMAP IDLE or  poll your mailbox periodically, but Yahoo doesn't have an official API for that.
Incoming Message Processing: Whenever a new email arrives, a notification is sent to the listener.Use the mail service API to get the email content and execute your function accordingly.
Remember that every email service has unique API restrictions and speed caps. When applying, make sure you  handle it gracefully.

This method allows you to create a secure and flexible solution that works with multiple email services without requiring users to  share their credentials directly.

Answering the comment:

Use a distributed task queue: To handle the increased workload generated by multiple users and email services, use a distributed task queue like Celery (for Python) or Sidekiq (for Ruby) to process incoming emails asynchronously. This will help you manage the load efficiently by distributing tasks among multiple workers and prevent blocking of resources.
Optimize API usage: Since email services have API rate limits and restrictions, it is essential to optimize your API usage. You can cache common API responses, implement a back-off strategy in case of rate limit errors, and use batch requests when possible to minimize the number of API calls.
Scale your infrastructure: To accommodate a growing number of users, you may need to scale your infrastructure horizontally by adding more servers or vertically by increasing the resources available to your existing servers. This can be done using cloud services like AWS, Google Cloud, or Azure, which provide auto-scaling features to adapt to changing workloads.
Use a load balancer: Implement a load balancer to distribute incoming traffic evenly among your servers. This will help prevent server overload and ensure that your application remains responsive even under high demand.
Monitor performance: Regularly monitor the performance of your application, including API usage, task processing times, and system resources. Set up alerts and notifications to inform you of any performance issues or bottlenecks, allowing you to take corrective action quickly.
By implementing these strategies, you can scale your OAuth-based email listening solution to handle a large number of users and email services efficiently, ensuring a reliable and secure experience for your customers.

Comment: How would scale be factored into this? If there are 100 users who want to listen to new emails in both gmail and outlook, how would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, you will need to store user credentials in one way or another in your app. Each IMAP connection needs to be authenticated, and you are going to make a lot of these. OAuth2 access tokens are also basically passwords – yes, you can't log in to the email account administration page with it, but you can still access and modify all the emails of that account.

Also, most email providers do not even offer OAuth2, or it has strict requirements that are hard to pass (e.g., Gmail requires you to go through an expensive verification process and may fail you if they do not like your use case).

So, in short, you need to treat access/refresh tokens exactly the same way you would treat regular passwords. Always encrypt stored credentials.

If you would use something like [EmailEngine](https://emailengine.app/) (NB! paid product), then it would encrypt and store credentials in its internal storage. And any time a new email is added to or deleted from any monitored email account, it sends you a webhook about it.